# Unable to access Docker container behind Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am attempting to access the whoami container running on my remote server, but can only get as far as a "404 page not found" error. I get the same result when attempting to access the traefik dashboard.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: # CLI arguments
      ## Globals
      - "--global.checkNewVersion=false"
      - "--global.sendAnonymousUsage=false"
      ## Entrypoint Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#configuration ##
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=https"
      - "--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      ## API Settings
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--log=true"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG" # (Default: error) DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.watch=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      ## Certificate Settings (Let's Encrypt) -  https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/#configuration-examples ##
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" # TBD - TESTING
    networks:
      - frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    security_opt:
      - "no-new-privileges:true" # https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#security-configuration
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "$USERDIR/ctmp/acme/acme.json:/acme.json:rw" # cert location - you must touch this file and change permissions to 600
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.rule=HostHeader(`traefik.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.service=api@internal"

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    networks:
      - frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=HostHeader(`whoami.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=http"

networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
```

$USERDIR and $DOMAIN are defined in my .env file.

All of the traefik logs are `info` or `debug` level with no errors appearing.

Comment: What the Output  `curl -s 127.0.0.1:8080/api/rawdata | jq .` ? See traefik the whoami Container? You may need a JSON formater "apt install jq"

Comment: I do not get any output when running that command (via SSH login to remote server).

Comment: Okay this should be a response from Traefik.

Comment: Why should I be seeing something on localhost though? I would expect it to be routing from the public IP address to the internal docker network IP address.

Comment: No that was just an example in your case you must of course `curl -s https://traefik.your-domain.com/api/rawdata | jq .` What do you have in your Traefik Static Config, so you have one?

Comment: All of my configuration is in the `docker-compose.yml`, I do not have any separate files. I still do not get any output with the curl command but I do get a log in the traefik container when I attempt it: `level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from <ip>:<port>: local error: tls: bad record MAC`. Doesn't seem like a problem given I am using the LE staging environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time right now but here is a quick code rewrite, but not tested.
It is just a slightly different method. But I think it leads to the same goal.

- You must include your ENV file
- traefik.http.routers.api.rule=HostHeader to =Host(`...). Whereby it is strange and should also work with HostHeader. [Link](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/)
- With this base you can now customize it. I use the HTTP chalange, but with the TLS chalange it should work.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: # CLI arguments
      ## Globals
      - "--global.checkNewVersion=false"
      - "--global.sendAnonymousUsage=false"
      ## Entrypoint Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#configuration ##
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      ## API Settings
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.insecure=false"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG" # (Default: error) DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      ## Certificate Settings
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=YOUR-EMAIL@your-domain.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    networks:
      - frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    security_opt:
      - "no-new-privileges:true" # https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#security-configuration
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirect.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirect.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami
    container_name: simple-service
    networks:
      - frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me the same result (404 page) except with a few new errors in the container logs:
`level=warning msg="Could not find network named 'http' for container '/traefik'!`
`level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"traefik-dc\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [traefik-dc]: acme: error: 400 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order...`

Comment: With `docker create network http` create the network. And were the A-records of your domains really placed on the host IP? Is Port 80 Open for the www?

Comment: Adding the http network resolves the warning, but same overall result. DNS looks fine as evidenced by 404 when container is running (and unable to connect when not running) but I get the same result when I use the IP address as well. nmap shows that port 80 is open.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Now it should work. Your error message was because your router rule was called HostHeader. But it must be called =Host(). I have edited my answer.

Comment: Interesting, my config now works with: api.insecure=false, HostHeader (instead of Host) and the staging LE certificate. The critical change appears to have been adding the `"traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=myresolver"` label. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes that is correct. It must also be set to false because we created the router api@internal. With api.insecure=true the API is set to port 8080.